# AddEditView (window) using WPF : passing Id to model construtor before opening form

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I am very new to WPF. I am trying to create Add/Edit form. I have also added Caliburn.Micro frameowrk for MVVM.

I have created one screen for `Add` or `Edit`. **I do not know how to pass model `Id` to my `ViewModel`. How?**

Currently my `View (Window)` works only for `Add` and not `Edit`.

- AddOrderViewModel.cs
- corresponding AddOrderView.xaml

The classes are like this:

```
 public class OrderAddEditViewModel : Screen {
        public OrderAddEditViewModel( ) {};

        // I do not know if this is normal approach or not
        public OrderAddEditViewModel(int orderId) { // Load Order from DB};
        ...
   }

public partial class OrderAddEditView : Window ...
```

Now, when pressing button on `Main form`, I am opening `OrderAddEditView`

```
       //This loads empty form for Add
       // What if I have OrderId and want to load it, HOW?
        var frm = new OrderAddEditView(); 
        frm.Show();
```

There is some magic behind, and `OrderAddEditView` knows which view model to use (this is WPF + `Caliburn.Micro`).

However, currently I want to pass "`OrderId`" to my `OrderAddEditViewModel`'s  constructor (this will load data from DB) and open `OrderAddEditView` so that constructor with id would be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `Caliburn.Micro`, there is a neat method who opens your `ViewModel`.
Its called `ActivateItem`.
To use it just write the following.

```
ActivateItem(new YourViewModel([some attributes]));
```

Update 2:
I almost forgot...
To use `ActivateItem` method, one of your `ViewModels` has to be the `Conductor`. I like to think about it like base of all views. That's mostly the first `ViewModel` who starts with your app (except login screen, if you have it). 
read about it more [here.](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens,%20Conductors%20and%20Composition)

Answer (score -2):

This is a very uggly solution:

You create a Constructor for OrderAddEditView class.

And pass the id for the DataContext in that constructor?

The ViewModel is the DataContext of the View...

Comment: Please, answer a question. If it is ugly suggest something, instead of just saying it is ugly. It is not how stackoverflow works. As I said I am new to WPF. Btw, I do not have construtor yet.  This was myu proposal, but if it is ugly, suggest something. I need Add_Edit form (one form for Add and Edit), thus I thought I have to use the same ViewModel - for Add it would be "empty", but for Edit, it would contain data). Moreover, my data access layer is outside WPF, it is as service, but to construct ViewModel I something have to call multiple services.

Comment: Well, than you should read about MVVM and you should navigate by ViewModel and not by Views. Much easier. For multiple states of View you can use VisualStates. (For example you create a service that makes a new instance of the view if you call that service and it adds your ViewModel instance as a DataContext. Than you just need to bind your new view to a ContentControl content.)